# How do I load my webview client using JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a problem loading my webview client on a javaFX application. The problem came when it says "Exception running application application.Main". Currently running using my SDK-11.02 and my file path is "C:\Fx\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib".

My VM Arguments:

```
--module-path "C:\Fx\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.base --add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism=ALL-UNNAMED
```

My Main Class:

```
package application;
    
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            
            primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX WebView Example");

            WebView webView = new WebView();

            webView.getEngine().load("https://eservices.police.gov.sg/content/policehubhome/homepage/police-report.html");

            BorderPane root = new BorderPane(webView);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
}
```

My Print StackTrace:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class com.sun.java.scene.web.WebViewHelper (in unnamed module @0x5d989a5a) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.scene to unnamed module @0x5d989a5a
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:821)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:719)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:642)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:600)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebView.<clinit>(WebView.java:1271)
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:18)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application application.Main
```

I seriously feel frustrated over a simple no brain problem. Please can somebody solve this for me? I will appreciate any kind soul to sort this problem out.

Comment: You're  missing `javafx.web` from the `add-modules` option, though I'm not sure if that's the only issue.

Comment: @James_D Bro thank you so much for solving this problem buddy. It's just that one missing ingredient for my gui to work.

Comment: @James_D I suggest either of you make an Answer of those comments, to be accepted and mark this as resolved.

Comment: @BasilBourque I was thinking the same as well. Glad you reminded him

Comment: @Big_Smoke If he does not post an Answer, know that you are welcome/encouraged on Stack Overflow to post and accept your own Answer to your own Question.